# Comparing linear vs. non-linear regression model for "best" fit

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

How, if at all, can one compare the "fit" of a simple linear vs. non-linear regression model to observed data?

I apologize if I didn't search long/hard enough for the answer, but I cannot find anything concrete.

-Patrick

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Can you share your purpose in comparing the fit of the different models? To develop a predictive model? To describe a particular data set? To provide evidence for or against a particular theory? You might choose different comparison approaches depending on your purpose.

Comment: Anne, at this point it is simply for description.  I would like to quantitatively be able to say that a non-linear fit is preferred.

Comment: Michelle, I use R.

Comment: Would using AIC/BIC or the LogLik be sound statistically to make a choice between non-linear and linear models on the same dataset?

Answer (score 7):

Perform cross-validation on each model on a development set to find the best hyper-parameters / accuracy estimate for each. Then check that the accuracy estimates are still valid on some held out data that you did not use during the model selection / parameter tuning phase.